# finding weekday with php getdate() function

Tags: php, date, weekday, getdate

I am trying to build a function in php where it takes the user input date, which can be any date within pretty much the last 20 years.  i tried to use the getdate() function in php to return to them the day of the week. 
here is what I have that isn't working.

```
$date="8/4/2010";//user input
$dateget=getdate($date);
echo $dateget; // i want an output like "monday" or "saturday"
```

when i run this code i get this error

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered (on the $dateget=getdate($date) line)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a timestamp for [getdate function](http://php.net/getdate). So maybe strtotime function can help.

```
$date="8/4/2010";//user input
$dateget=getdate(strtotime($date));
echo $dateget['weekday'];
```